# failed to fetch nginx packages

Tags: nginx

Failed to fetch http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'nginx/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

Answer (score 0):

Armhf packages are not built by nginx.org. List of supported architectures: http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#mainline